# Identify Non English Chat

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-cx

How to let chatbot identify if customer is chatting in Chinese? I create a Non English intent but it is not working

When customer chatting in Chinese, chatbot will reply "Sorry. I am only able to chat in English"